# ubuntu source code, for what?

Tags: compiling, dvd, source

I found [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.3/release/source/) which contains Ubuntu 12.04 source code. It's about 3 DVDs and sizing 10GB.

I have downloaded all DVDs but I didn't find any installers in it. I wonder if there is a way I can make a custom Ubuntu CD by just choosing the needed open source software from my company. Is that possible?

What can I benefit from these DVDs right now? any help would be appreciated.

By the way I don't find an answer for my question in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82302/how-to-compile-ubuntu-from-source-code)

Comment: There is an easier method: take your pick http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679 with desktop as base. Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/409651#409651 with the server version as a base. The last one is the easiest since it holds the least software. You can put packages onto the disc (even those that are not in the repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Linux with just the software, you want, why not try [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/)? By the way, you also have Ubuntu [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) and [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch).

I have never tried those, and I think you'll probably be more happy with Arch, which also has its own Live CD creation tool with all info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Building_a_Live_CD) :) plus the wiki of Arch is amazing! You'll definitely find all you need to know there!

Long story short...you don't need to compile the whole distribution to customize it the way you want :P It would probably took WAY too much time at your work, except if you don't have nothing else to do.

Comment: Sadly, I want only Ubuntu! I don't ever prefer another distro. Thanks for your effort @Alko

Comment: LiveCDCustomization does not use Ubuntu source code as I mentioned in my question

Comment: why would you want to use source code? Yau just have to select the packages you want

Comment: I want to build it simply offline. for many reasons. I don't want to customize only the ubuntu cd/dvd which is not more than 1.5GB. If I have 10GB I wonder that bigger is better

Comment: Emmm, its not any better, it just uses precious space :P if you want to create an installation with custom packages preinstalled, then I think you need a custom live CD installation...else I don't know what you want to accomplish..

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago we needed a simple method to get ubuntu on a desktop. What I did was the following.

- Using a testmachine I installed Ubuntu from a standard image (preferably an LTS version)
- I removed all software that I didn't want
- I installed all software needed, configured the desktop etc to what I thought was best
- For software like teamviewer that creates a unique ID for each machine, I did NOT start it to avoid creating that unique ID

Now I had this clean and "perfect" setup, I needed a way to get it on a new PC.

- I created an image using Clonezilla.
- I copied this image on a USB stick (or CD or DVD).
- I used a second USB stick to put clonezilla on, which can be started from that usb stick.
- I started the process of installing the ubuntu image from the stick using clonezilla
- This process includes how to start Clonezilla from CD or USB (editing bios etc)
- Once I had all steps in this process working without guessing what to do, I made screenshots of each step, put them in a Word/Writer document with instructions what keys to press etc.

  - NB: I created the screenshots with my phone as I didn't know how to do this when using Clonezilla - ugly but it worked.
- When I had this installation manual ready, I tried it on another person, of he could do this without my help.
- When this worked, I created a PDF with the manual, two usb sticks per install, and gave it out to whoever needed it.

The result was a 10 minute installation process with a working Ubuntu desktop. The person who's going to do these installs has to be comfortable doing this, but after a while it's very easy.

You should use an LTS version to avoid having to do this all over after 18 months, when the this Ubuntu version is not updated anymore.

We used one type/brand of computer. Different computers probably have different bios screens, and that might be confusing to many people. So depending on this and on the person doing the install, this might be a problem.

I don't know if this helps you or not. Maybe you want a normal installation cd like the one you download. Like it or not, it's an option you can consider.

Comment: I've done almost the same thing. But my question is different